# Constraints Crash

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

I created two constraints to keep my label in centre both on 3.5" iPhone and 4" iPhone. I've done it in code:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 216, 320, 137)];
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-UltraLight" size:size];
[label setFont:font];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[label setAlpha:0];
[label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[label setText:text];
self.alertLabel = label;
[self.timeLabel setHidden:YES];
NSLayoutConstraint *centerLayoutY = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:self.view.center.y relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:label attribute:label.center.y multiplier:1 constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint *centerLayoutX = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:self.view.center.x relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:label attribute:label.center.x multiplier:1 constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:centerLayoutY];
[self.view addConstraint:centerLayoutX];
[self.view addSubview:label];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[label setAlpha:0.6f];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

When I run app it crashes:

```
2014-07-03 18:24:12.361 NigthLigth[2550:60b] The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x8f544d0 H:[UILabel:0x8f533c0]-(0)-[UIView:0x8c57d30]>
When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
2014-07-03 18:24:12.362 NigthLigth[2550:60b] View hierarchy unprepared for constraint.
Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x8f544d0 H:[UILabel:0x8f533c0]-(0)-[UIView:0x8c57d30]>
Container hierarchy: 
<UIView: 0x8c57d30; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8e558a0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8c57f10>>
   | <UIImageView: 0x8c580c0; frame = (0 -44; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8c581c0>>
   | <UILabel: 0x8c5af80; frame = (34.5 182.5; 251 115); text = '06:24'; clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8c5b0b0>>
   | <_UILayoutGuide: 0x8e6ccb0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e6cdc0>>
   | <_UILayoutGuide: 0x8e6d240; frame = (0 480; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x8e6d2b0>>
View not found in container hierarchy: <UILabel: 0x8f533c0; frame = (0 216; 320 137); text = 'Cannot Snooze'; alpha = 0; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8f42870>>
That view's superview: NO SUPERVIEW
2014-07-03 18:24:12.372 NigthLigth[2550:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal. constraint:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8f544d0 H:[UILabel:0x8f533c0]-(0)-[UIView:0x8c57d30]> view:<UIView: 0x8c57d30; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8e558a0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8c57f10>>'
```

What's Wrong?

Comment: Why not use IB? Think of all the coding you'll save! And why are you using < iOS 4.0 style animations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing several things incorrectly. First, you should just use alloc init with your label, you shouldn't be setting a frame. You also need to set the label's translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property to NO. Second, you need to add the subview to its superview before you add the constraints not after.  Third, the attribute parameter shouldn't be something like "label.center.y", it should be one of the NSLayoutAttribute types, like NSLayoutAttributeCenterY.